# Microsoft.Azure.Search (sdk v3.0.3) don't return all the facets correctly

Tags: azure, faceted-search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

When I use Microsoft.Azure.Search (v3.0.3)'s "SearchAsync" and "Search" methods to return the indexed items, the sdk doesn't return all the facets.

However; when I try the same thing using Postman, it returns all the facets correctly.

Could this be a bug of the sdk (I believe it is as a direct call to an sdk method doesn't return the all the facets correctly - but couldn't find any records about this possible bug)? If yes, is there a fix for this for the sdk? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
After spending some more time, I have found out that the bug is not .NET SDK Specific.

Both .NET SDK and REST API appear to have this problem and none of them returns all the facets. Can you please tell me is there a known bug for this and what is the fix for it?

Please see the following example;

There must be 2 Coaching facets but only 1 is returning from the Azure Search Service.

The new search query(facet specialisms added)

```
https://MYPROJECT-search.search.windows.net/indexes/myproject-directory-qa/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&$count=true&facet=specialisms&$filter=listingType eq 'Therapist'
 "Coaching:Development coaching", --> This doesn't return as a facet.
 "Coaching:Executive coaching", -->This returns fine.


  "@search.facets": {
        "specialisms@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.QueryResultFacet)",
        "specialisms": [
            {
                "count": 5,
                "value": "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Depression"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Addiction, self-harm and eating disorders:Obsessions"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Post-traumatic stress"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Coaching:Executive coaching"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Identity, culture and spirituality:Self esteem"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Relationships, family and children:Pregnancy related issues"
            },
            {
                "count": 4,
                "value": "Stress and work:Redundancy"
            },
            {
                "count": 3,
                "value": "Addiction, self-harm and eating disorders:Eating disorders"
            },
            {
                "count": 3,
                "value": "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Bereavement"
            },
            {
                "count": 3,
                "value": "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Loss"
            }
        ]
    },


{
            "@search.score": 1,
            "contactId": "df394997-6e94-e711-80ed-3863bb34db00",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.58586,
                    51.47873
                ],
                "crs": {
                    "type": "name",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "EPSG:4326"
                    }
                }
            },
            "profileImageUrl": "https://myprojectwebqa.blob.core.windows.net/profileimage/3e31457c-5113-4062-b960-30f038ce7bfc.jpg",
            "locationText": "Bristol",
            "listingType": "Therapist",
            "disabledAccess": true,
            "flexibleHours": true,
            "offersConcessionaryRates": false,
            "homeVisits": true,
            "howIWillWork": "<p>Some test data</p>",
            "specialisms": [
                "Health related issues:Asperger syndrome",
                "Health related issues:Chronic fatigue syndrome/ME",
                "Addiction, self-harm and eating disorders:Addictions",
                "Addiction, self-harm and eating disorders:Eating disorders",
                "Addiction, self-harm and eating disorders:Obsessions",
                "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Bereavement",
                "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Depression",
                "Anxiety, depression and trauma:Loss",
                "Coaching:Development coaching",
                "Coaching:Executive coaching",
                "Identity, culture and spirituality:Self esteem",
                "Identity, culture and spirituality:Sexuality",
                "Relationships, family and children:Infertility",
                "Relationships, family and children:Relationships",
                "Stress and work:Redundancy"
            ],
            "clientele": [
                "Adults",
                "Children",
                "Groups"
            ],
            "approaches": [
                "CBT",
                "Cognitive",
                "Psychoanalytic",
                "Psychosynthesis"
            ],
            "sessionTypes": [
                "Home visits",
                "Long-term face to face work"
            ],
            "hourlyRate": 50,
            "fullName": "Test Name",
            "id": "ZWUwNGIyNjYtYjQ5Ny1lNzExLTgwZTktMzg2M2JiMzY0MGI4"
        }
```

Please see details below;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my case I have found out that by default the Azure Search Service returns 10 of the facets. That is why I couldn't see all my facets.

After updating my search query as follows, I have fixed my problem and now I can see all my facets in the search results - please see the facet bit updated to this; facet=specialisms, **count:9999**.

```
 https://MYPROJECTNAME-search.search.windows.net/indexes/MYPROJECTNAME-directory-qa/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&$count=true&facet=specialisms, count:9999&facet=clientele, count:9999&$filter=listingType eq 'Therapist'
```

For the Microsoft documentation, please see the following link.

"max # of facet terms; default is 10"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents